# Get value of a checkbox?

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox, how do I get its value using jquery? I have this example from searching:

```
var checked = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').val() != undefined;
```

but how do I specify which checkbox I'm interested in, I want to only examine a checkbox with a particular id?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even easier

```
if($('#foo').is(':checked')){
    //code here
}
```

Comment: Don't place the tag name `input` before an ID. It slows down the selector.

Answer (score 2):

```
var checked = $('input#foo:checked');

if ( checked.length && checked.val().length ) {
   // do something with checked
}
```

Comment: Just a note. If I remember correctly, placing the tag name before an ID will actually slow down the selector.

Comment: I don't think anyone cares about the performance of something so trivial. No one would really notice.

Comment: With all due respect, nonsense. Performance is always important with selectors. You are negating the benefit of using an ID when you place the tag name before. If it is so trivial, then why use IDs at all? It is a bad practice that shouldn't be perpetuated.

Comment: ...to further illustrate, you cached the jQuery object so you wouldn't have to run the selector twice. Running the selector twice *without* the tag in the selector can be faster than running it once *with* the tag in the selector. Ok, I'm done now. :o)

Comment: The difference is in nano/milliseconds unless you're doing it hundreds of times in a loop. You will *not* notice it.

Comment: Haha... Meder certainly wouldnt last 5 minutes at my work place. Always embrace best practice. Performance is always important...

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's `is()` along with the `:checked` selector:

```
var $theCheckbox = $('#theID');

if( $theCheckbox.is(':checked') ) {
    var checked = $theCheckbox.val();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BYagp/1/

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by value?  You can tell whether a box is checked with the `checked` attribute.  If it's checked, the value it sends to the server if the form submitted is in the `value` attribute.

```
var mybox = $('input#myid');
if (mybox.length > 0 && mybox[0].checked) {
    // do something, or use mybox[0].value
} else {
}
```

Comment: `checked` property doesn't exist on the jQuery object so that will always fail unless you do `[0].checked`

Comment: Good catch, meder; serves me right for not testing.  Is that better?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your id is #myid, then:

```
var checked = $('input[type="checkbox"]#myid').attr('checked');
if (checked) {
   //box is checked
} else {

}
```