# Getting the value of a text or checkbox with jQuery and putting it into a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$("input[id^='Order_'], input[id^='Default_']")
   .change(function (e) {
      var type = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[0];
      updateField('Menu', $(this), type);
});

The input with an id of 'Order_' has a type="text"
The input with an id of 'Default_' has a type="checkbox"
```

In my updateField I have a problem:

```
function updateField(entity, obj, type) {
    var val = obj.val();
    var idArr = obj.attr("id");
    var idTmp = idArr.split("_");
    var id = idTmp[1];
    var pkrk = $("span[id='refKey_" + id + "']").html();
```

The problem is that the code works good for the text but not for the checkbox. If the checkbox is checked or not then it still returns true. Is there a way that I can get the value of if the checkbox is checked or not and either put the string "true" or "false" into the variable  val  while still having the correct value put into   val if the date is coming from the Order_ ?

```
So if the value of Order_ field is 25 then val = "25"
So if the value of Default_ checkbox is true the val = "true"
So if the value of Default_ checkbox is false the val = "false"
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064629/get-value-of-a-checkbox

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think my situation is a bit different as somehow I need to decide if it is a checkbox or text field and based on that decision then I need a different way to get the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the checkbox doesnt have any "value". Instead of using the `val()` function in jQuery search for the attribute "checked".
This can be done as such:

```
var checked = !!$("checkbox selector").attr("checked");
```

Or using the jQuery selectors

```
var checked = $("checkbox selector").is(":checked");
```

So the `attr()` function will return undefined if the checkbox tag doesnt contain the attribute "checked" and that is the same as the unchecked state of the checkbox.

Comment: But I want to put this into the variable called "val" and I need some logic that will be different if it is a checkbox or a text field. Is there a way I check the value of the obj that is passed to updateField and then do something different depending on the kind of object?

Comment: @Jessica You could use `obj.attr("type") === "checkbox"` to determine if its a checkbox your currently handeling (and beware of the confiusion the function argument type creates).